# OpenCV least square (solve) solution accuracy

Tags: c++, opencv, least-squares

I am using the OpenCV method solve (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#solve) in C++ to fit a curve (grade 3, ax^3+bx^2+cx+d) through a set of points. I am solving A * x = B, A contain the powers of the points x-coordinates (so x^3, x^2, x^1, 1), and B contains the y coordinates of the points, x (Matrix) contains the parameters a, b, c and d.

I am using the flag DECOMP_QR on cv::solve to fit the curve.

The problem I am facing is that the set of points do not neccessarily follow a mathematical function (e.g. the function changes it's equation, see picture). So, in order to fit an accurate curve, I need to split the set of points where the curvature changes. In case of the picture below, I would split the regression at the index where the curve starts. So I need to detect where the curvature changes.

So, if I don't split, I'll get the yellow curve as a result, which is inaccurate. What I want is the blue curve.

[image: linear regression inaccuracy]

Finding curvature changes:
To find out where the curvature changes, I want to use the **solution accuracy**. 
So basically:

```
int splitIndex = 0;

for(int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < numberOfPoints; pointIndex += 5) {
      cv::Range rowR = Range(0, pointIndex);         //Selected rows to index
      cv::Range colR = Range(0,3);               //Grade: 3 (x^3)
      cv::Mat x;
      bool res = cv::solve(A(rowR, colR), B(rowR, Range(0,1)),x , DECOMP_QR);
      if(res == true) {
                //Check for accuracy
                if (accuracy too bad) {
                          splitIndex = pointIndex;
                          return splitIndex;
                }
      }
}
```

My questions are:
- is there a way of getting the accuracy / standard deviation from the solve command (efficiently & fast, because of real-time application (around 1ms compute time left))
- is this a good way of finding the curvature change / does anyone know a better way?

Thanks :)

Comment: The LS method consists in minimizing over `x` the "error" `square (Ax-B)`. The accuracy is simply obtained by calculating this value, for the obtained `x`. This corresponds to the sum of the square difference between the `y[i]` and the `z[i]` obtained by applying the polynomial on the `x[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because I am in a time-critical environment, I wanted to know if the accuracy is already calculated by the solve method? If not, I will calculate it manually

Comment: In my understanding, the solve method solves a linear system, and doest not need to evaluate the resulting optimal  error for that. I don't use the cv library, but I will be really surprised that cv solver performs this error estimation.